# HTML Resize Div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I am working on an online presentation editor.

I have a div (which should be the slide - the format is 16x9)

If the user decides to export it as pdf, the div should resize to 1920x1080, and then it should be exported (so that the pdf is not the same size as the user window, but always 1920 x 10800. My problem is, that if I set the width in JS like this:

```
$('#content').css('min-width', `1920px`);
$('#content').css('min-height', `1080px`);

$('#content').css('width', `1920px`);
$('#content').css('height', `1080px`);
```

only the container resizes, but the content doesn't.

[This is what the slide looks like in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdQa2.png)

[This is what the exported pdf looks like because the content doesn't resize.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMfuT.png)

If you have any idea, please let me know.

HTML:

```
<div style="background-color: green" id="content">
   <h1 style="color: black">Hallo Welt</h1>
   <p>Hallo 3CHIF!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: why do it so comlicated and fixed pixel height and width instead of using 100vw/100vh to adjust to what ever screen is used. Then use a print query to adjust the design specifically for printing.

Comment: Well, i am resizing it so that's no problem. I was using pixels to calculate the size for the pdf (it only takes pixels as the size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe there's other solutions (or even better solutions), but I tought about `scale()`, this will scale the `div` and consequently, it's contents.

So, how I did it:

I estipulated the desired width and height (in your case, 1920x1080), then I got the `div` current size.
Divided the desired sizes by current sizes to get the "ratio", then used the CSS `transform` to set the new `scale(x, y)`, as you can see in the below example.

You can base yourself in the code to get your solution

```js
var desiredWid = 1920;
var desiredHei = 1080;

var theDiv = $("#content");
var currentWid = theDiv.width();
var currentHei = theDiv.height();

var ratioW = desiredWid / currentWid;
var ratioH = desiredHei / currentHei;

theDiv.css("transform","scale(" + ratioW + "," + ratioH + ")")

var currentSizes = theDiv[0].getBoundingClientRect();
console.log("Adjusted Size:", currentSizes.width + " x " + currentSizes.height)
```

```css
#content {
  width: 2500px;
  height: 1200px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">Original Size: 2500x1200</div>
```

I used jQuery since I saw you are using, but you can do it with pure JS also.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never thought of using "scale". It's working great.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#content{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

if you want to have initiate max with or height you can add it to css too
then see if .css work or not
or must I say
then use js

Comment: I don't think CSS works right there because I am trying to change the height & width just for the export. As I said the width and height of the container changes but the content doesnt.

Comment: you can add width height 100% in js too 
Look max-width or max-height means
whatever the width or height is as long as it is under that certain value it ok
it does not have any effect on the with beneath the value
so you must determine the width(or height) of the div